# Splitting an address string into separate variables - Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I've been struggle with splitting an address field in my database into it's separate components.

I am pulling address data from my database that is stored in column #company_address# . The data looks like this when I output it:

Address1
Address2 (Not always present)
City, State Zip (Sometimes there is a comma, sometimes there is not)

I would like to break up the string in #company_address# and assign each part of the address to it's own variable:
variable1 - address1
variable2 - address2
variable3 - city
variable4 - state
variable5 - zip

Once I have that data, I will enter it back into the db in its seperated form.

I have tried using the listtoarray function but it assigns the whole string to one array element and seems to skip the address2 line entirely.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<!--- Select ticket record --->
 <cfquery name="get_ticket" datasource="#datasource#">
   SELECT *
   FROM closed_tickets
   where ticket_id = #url.ticket_id#
 </cfquery>

<cfoutput>

<cfset list = "#get_ticket.company_address#">
<cfset arr = listToArray (list, 'ch(13)' ,false,true)>
<cfdump var="#arr#">

</cfoutput>
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: OT: Use `<cfqueryparam>` before something bad happens. "See Little Bobby Tables"

Comment: Yeah I know. Just use that when testing code, then I parameterize it.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and include it future posts, just so you don't get the sql injection lecture from us every time .. and it ensures you don't forget. Win win. ;-)

Comment: Or unintentionally cause a copy-paster to put out horribly insecure code. Granted, you can't control how your code is used by someone else, but it never hurts to supply them with proper code, even if they can't/won't understand it. :-)

Comment: Also this very firmly falls into Garbage In, Garbage Out territory. If you have any control over this before it goes into your database, that would be a better way to handle it. But as it stands, you are relying on behaviors that may or may not exist. This method will break if an address is entered without carriage returns (`chr(13)`), but it will contain bad data if your application starts inserting full CRLFs (`chr(13)chr(10)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `chr(13)` as a string. Use the following.

```
<cfset arr = listToArray (list, chr(13) , false, true)>
```

Comment: That throws an error: No matching function [CH] found

Comment: It should be `chr`. Try that

Comment: I'd also recommend handling `chr(10)`s in the list.